# jQuery: why is an integer being added to a variable like a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables, integer

So I'm trying to take the variable that increments in a for statement, and add an integer to it... but for some reason, it's adding the integer as though it were a string; other operations like subtraction or multiplication work as expected.

Why is this happening? Edit: I've added the whole function; the problem in question is where I try to add 2 to the variable x.

What confuses me is that I'm able to use x no problem, in an .eq() object for example...

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea').bind('paste', function (e){
        inputGroup = $(this).parent();
        var ob = $(this);
        if (e.type == 'paste'){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var data = ob.val();
                var tabbed = data.replace(/\n/g, "\t");
                var cells = tabbed.split("\t");
                for(var x in cells) {
                    foo = x + 2;
                    alert(foo);
                    $(inputGroup).find('input').eq(x).val(cells[x]);
                }
            }, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how is `cells` being defined?

Comment: You don't need all those variables. Just: `var cells = ob.val().replace(...).split('\t');`

Comment: @Sime: hehe thanks. I'm still working on this code, so there's some bloat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because `x` is a string that just looks like a number. Cast to `Number` first and you'll get the result you expect:

```
"1" + 2 = "12"
Number("1") + 2 = 3
```

**EDIT :** Now that I see you are using `split` to turn a string into an array, your problem is **definitely** that you are concatenating strings. Cast to `Number` first, and your problem is solved.

Yes other arithmetic operations will work, since they will implicitly cast the operands to Numbers. Confusingly, `"2" * 3` will in fact evaluate to the integer `6`. Welcome to Javascript.

-tjw

Comment: @Travis The unary `+` operator is a shorthand for `Number()`: `+'1' + 2 === 3`

Comment: Weird... it seems bizarre that x in this case would be a string, given the fact that x is being used to count the array.

Comment: @Sime True, thanks for pointing that out. I use the full words because I like it when other people can actually read and understand my Javascript without wondering if it's actually written in Perl.

Comment: @Travis `+x` and `Number(x)` do the same thing. This means that in this case `+x` wins because it's shorter. Smaller codesize = better. I've received lots of up-votes for providing the smallest solution. When there are multiple equally valid solutions (answers), the answer with the smallest codesize is the most attractive one (and usually gets accepted). I recommend you to code towards smart, sophisticated solutions and don't care so much whether or not beginners can read your code.

Comment: `smaller codesize = better`. That's nice, good for you. I prefer to write code that people can read better, instead of code computers can read better. You save your 6 bytes; I'll write code that doesn't make my maintainers want to kill themselves. I see that you are still a student; good luck getting hired in industry with that attitude. I'm not trying to be mean, I'm honestly trying to help you. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth

Comment: @Travis Are you suggesting that for a JavaScript programmer `+x` is harder to read than `Number(x)`? [The unary + operator is defined in the spec.](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6) Beginners/hobbyists don't read the spec, maintainers/professionals  **should**. What kind of maintainers would want to kill themselves over `+x`? Probably those who don't read the spec (and aren't possibly even aware that there is a spec - and where to find it). Btw, the jQuery source code contains one instance of `+x` and zero instances of `Number(x)`.

Comment: @Travis Also, this is most certainly not premature optimization. It's simply choosing the better solution. When two solutions provide the same functionality, then the criterion becomes code-size. For instance, `[]` is better than `new Array()` - this is a fact. I'm simply applying logic and common sense to choose the better solution. In case that your team members don't understand certain code conventions (like `[]` is preferred over `new Array()`), then the correct approach is to **teach them**. Using `new Array()` just to make sure that everybody understands the code is not a good approach.

Comment: `When two solutions provide the same functionality, then the criterion becomes code-size`. I'm very sorry that you think that. Like I said, I was just trying to help you, but I'm not going to change your mind. Good luck in your career.

Comment: @Travis Hey NHF, I just love to debate `:)`. During debates, I implicitly take on slightly excessive stances - but that only lures proper arguments from the other side. Then, after an exchange of arguments, my stance usually shifts towards middle ground. I'm sorry that you don't want to continue this, I'd love to hear proper arguments. Again, NHF.

Comment: When you're happily coding for and by yourself, coding standards can be whatever looks right to you. When you are on a team of 5, 10, 100 other people, you need to be conscious that certain syntax constructs are simply not easy to read from a quick glance. For example, at my job I regularly write code in Erlang, Java, and Javascript, and switch between these on a daily basis. If I used these language-specific syntax idiosyncracies, not only will QA wonder wtf it means, I would be wishing I had just used `Number` when I'm trying to quickly read through a few hundred lines of code a week later.

Comment: When I was a student, I held many stances on things similar to this that, now that I've been working in the industry for a little while, I find ridiculous. I hope that the same thing happens to you. If you are ever asked about this topic in a job interview, please answer it my way. I'm serious, you won't get hired. Unfortunately, I don't have time to write an essay on why you're wrong. ;-) See you around SO.

Answer (score 2):

Without more code, specifically the initialization of cells, I can't tell you the exact reason. But you can simply call `parseInt()` on `x` to turn it into an integer for addition

```
for(var x in cells) {
    foo = parseInt(x, 10) + 2;
    $(inputGroup).find('input').eq(foo).val(cells[x]);
}
```

Comment: When using parseInt, always specify the radix: `parseInt(x, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `+` is a String concatenation but there is no equivalent String method for `*` or `/` so when using those it cast the value as a Number.  Just cast `x` as an integer:

```
for(var x in cells) {
    foo = parseInt(x, 10) + 2;
    $(inputGroup).find('input').eq(foo).val(cells[x]);
}
```

The `10` in `parseInt` is saying to use a base 10 number system (as opposed to hex 16, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `x` *is* a string.  That's why.

There's a nice trick for casting strings as numbers in JavaScript that hasn't been mentioned though:

```
for(var x in cells) {
  // Without the "var" here, you're setting a global
  //  variable during each loop iteration.
  var foo = +x + 2;

  $(inputGroup).find('input').eq(foo).val(cells[x]);
}
```

Comment: Your syntax tricks make everyone else's eyes bleed. `Number` is much more readable.

Comment: If your eyes are bleeding, you should get away from the keyboard and see a doctor!  Using the unary operator is pretty run-of-the-mill JavaScript once you've used it for long.